# If $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$, the arc length of graph of $f_n$ converges to the arc lenth of graph of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, arc-length

If $f$ and $f_n$ are continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$, and $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$, the the arc length of graph of $f_n$ converges to the arc lenth of graph of $f$ ?

I feel this proposition is wrong, but I cannot came up with some counter-example. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810336/does-there-exist-a-if-and-only-if-condition-so-that-arc-length-of-a-convergent-s), answer said if every $f_n$ is convex, the lengths of graphs converge but this is sufficient condition.

I would be happy to give you a counter-example.

Comment: counterexample: $f_n:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$, $f_n(t)=\frac1n\sin(n^2t)$.

Comment: what's true in general is $L(f)\le\liminf L(f_n)$.

Comment: Consider the sequence $f_n$ as follows: each $f_n$ divides the interval $[0,1]$ into $2n$ contiguous intervals such that on every odd interval (1st, 3rd, 5th, etc), the function is linear with slope 1, starting at zero. And on each even interval, it is also linear with slope -1 starting at the peack and going down to zero, so that you have a saw. By Pythagoras theorem, this sequence has arclength $\sqrt{2}$ and converges uniformly to the function $f(x) = 0$ which has arclength 1.

Comment: The comment by @WillM. provides a simple example except that the question asked for continuously differentiable functions. So you need to smooth out the corners of the saw. That gives an example that's easy to see and to understand but hard to write down because the smoothing can be messy.  That's why a comment and an answer used rapidly oscillating sine functions with small amplitude instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample**. Take $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f=0$ in $[0,1]$. On the other hand, the limit of the arclength of $f_n$ over $[0,1]$ is
$$
\begin{align}L_n&=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\cos^2(nx)}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}\,dt\to \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}\,dt>1
\end{align}$$
which strictly greater than $1$, the arclenght of $f$ over $[0,1]$.

P.S. For the limit of $L_n$ we applied  [Proving a question about the average of a periodic function formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771235/proving-a-question-about-the-average-of-a-periodic-function-formula)

Comment: Thank you for your example! The limit means average ?

Comment: The limit IS the mean value of the integral over a period.

Comment: OK. I understood! Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: @calico I included a reference for the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, another nerd counterexample.

Consider $I=[-1,1]$.

Take $f_1:I\to \Bbb R$ to be the function whose graph is the upper circle of diameter $I$. Its clear that its length is $\pi$ and it also holds that $|f_1(x)|\le 1$.

Take $f_2:I\to\Bbb R$ to be the function whose graph is

- the upper semicircle of diameter $[-1,0]$
- the upper semicircle of diameter $[0,1]$.

It is also clear that the length of its graph is, another time $\pi$.
Also holds that $|f_2(x)|\le\frac{1}{2}$.

Take $f_3:I\to\Bbb R$ to be the function whose graph is:

- The upper semicircle of diameter $[-1,-1/2]$
- The upper semicircle of diameter $[-1/2,0]$
- The upper semicircle of diameter $[0,1/2]$
- The upper semicircle of diameter $[1/2,1]$

The length of the graph is, another time $\pi$ and $|f_3(x)|\le \frac{1}{2^2}$.

Following inductively this construction, we get a sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ such that the length of its graphs is always $\pi$ but $|f_n(x)|\le\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, so $f_n\to0$ uniformly on $I$.

BUT the length of the graph of the limit function isn't $\pi$, but $2$.

PS: One can use this example to make a FALSE proof of the fact that $\pi=2$.